# Maintaining values of lists after copying

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

```
list1=["a","b","c","d"]
list2 = list1

list1.remove("a")

print(list1,list2) ----> ['b', 'c', 'd'] ['b', 'c', 'd']
```

In the list mentioned above, I want to retain old values which I had copied from list1 to list2.

But after I modify list1, list2 is still pointing to list1 contents.

How can I prevent this from happening and have list2 containing the values `["a","b","c","d"]`

Comment: ```list2 = list1[::]```

Comment: `list2 = list1` This does NOT make a copy of list1.  It creates a new name list2 that refers to the SAME object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use copy() like this

```
list1=["a","b","c","d"]
list2 = list1.copy()
list1.remove("a")
print(list1,list2)   # ['b', 'c', 'd'] ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
```

or list slicing

```
list1=["a","b","c","d"]
list2 = list1[:]
list1.remove("a")
print(list1,list2)   # ['b', 'c', 'd'] ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
```

or list()

```
list1=["a","b","c","d"]
list2 = list(list1)
list1.remove("a")
print(list1,list2)   # ['b', 'c', 'd'] ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
```